# GetCursorPos only returning x value

Tags: winapi, vb6, cursor-position

I saw a thread on an [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vblanguage/thread/b3e97c02-e713-4771-a448-ac521fbbe4ac) where there was an issue with 32-bit vs. 64-bit integers.  I'm not sure if that is my issue, but it seems as though this code should work, so I'm a bit confused.

I'm running VB6 in compatiblity mode (XP SP2) in Windows 7 64-bit.

```
Type POINTAPI ' This holds the logical cursor information
    x As Integer
    y As Integer
End Type

Public Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
```

In `Timer1_Timer()`...

```
Dim mousePos As POINTAPI
Call GetCursorPos(mousePos)
MsgBox mousePos.x & " " & mousePos.y
```

This message box shows the correct value for the x coordinate of the mouse, but it shows `"0"` for `y`, no matter where the mouse is on the screen.  Also, `GetCursorPos()` is returning `1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In VB6 the Integer data type is a 16-bit number. You have to use Long as this is a 32-bit number.

```
Type POINTAPI ' This holds the logical cursor information
  x As Long
  y As Long
End Type

Public Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
```

or use:

```
Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (lpPoint As POINT_TYPE) As Long
```

Comment: Whoops.  I thought integer would have been 32-bit and long 64-bit.  Interesting.  Thanks!

Comment: @Michael carry over from 16 Bit programming era

Answer (score 4):

If your are running in VB6 your POINTAPI declaration needs to use a Long for your point declaration:

```
Type POINTAPI ' This holds the logical cursor information 
    x As Long
    y As Long 
End Type
```

---

As far as returning a 1, that means you were successful:

**Return Value** Long -- NonZero on success, zero on failure. Sets GetLastError

*"From Visual Basic Programmer's Guide to the Win32 API"*

Comment: +1 for consulting [Daniel Appleman's book Visual Basic Programmer's Guide to the Win32 API](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Appleman-Visual-Basic-Programmers-CD-Rom/dp/0672315904)